# change ldap password with phpldap taking in mind assigned policies

Tags: php, ldap, password-policy

I am trying to write a shiny php service that would allow users to change their passwords.
I've come to usage of ldap_modify function. All is ok, I pass dn and new user password (*or its hash*), and user can successfully log in afterwards.

The problem is that this user has a password policy assigned that forbids password lengths < 2. After passing such password (*or hash*) to ldap_modify I get no errors, exceptions, whatever.

Why doesn't ldap check passwords according to assigned password policies?

As a temporary solution I can read policy entry and check length manually...

Comment: Step 1. Look through your policies and record what enforcements are currently in place, and modify your code accordingly. Step 2. Profit... But if I may enquire, why are you allowing users to change password(s) through PHP?

Comment: Thanks. So you are suggesting to manually check enforcements ?
My projects uses LDAP autorization and user must have an option of changing password

Comment: Indeed, for the time being. You could look into using some already created LDAP management packages which are available on github. https://github.com/adldap/adLDAP -- Looks promising from an initial glimpse

Comment: You could even look through the *user functions* and trace how this package catches password policies

Comment: Thanks again. All projects I've seen to this moment had a rather robust documentation on password change but had password restrictions hardcoded or none at all. I will check further what you've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There is a commandline-tool called `ldappasswd` (on some linux-distros it's called `slappasswd` IIRC) which should be used to generate a passwords hash. This tool IIRC validates the entered password against the password policy that has been set for the given user.

When you manually alter the password-value the LDAP-Server has no chance of checking it as it's an attribute like all the other ones so you can alter it without the server interfering. And as you set a hash as value the LDAP-Server has no chance in knowing whether the password matches the directives of the password policy as it never actually gets to see the password in an unhashed state. Therefore you'll have to check the policy by yourself **before** hashing the password.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: so the problem was that policy I was testing on had attribute `pwdCheckQuality` set to 0 which disabled all checking... Second problem was that admin users in LDAP ignore password policies - I had to do all the testing on simple user